# Non-table json value from a DataTables ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I'm populating a 'DataTable' table via ajax and it works fine. However, I'd like to also return a pipe-separated serialised string of unique IDs which form the rows to be displayed. I'm using the dataSrc option in a standard ajax call:

```
$('#displayRecords').dataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
    "ajax": {
    "url": "globalJSON/recordsTable.php",
    "dataSrc": "recordsTable"
    }
});
```

So that works but on top of the recordsTable array within the json return, I'd also like to fetch the string 'recordsSerialised' and obviously use it in a wider scope.

I think using the ajax call as function is the answer but I am not sure how to implement it. The documentation reads as if I just fetch the json via an alternative $.ajax, $.post, $.whatever and pass the return into the function variables. Can anyone verify that I'm on the right lines. If not, any suggestions or corrections would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  What you can do is call a function for `dataSrc`, as long as you `return` the appropriate data for the DataTable.  Say your json response contains 2 arrays, `recordsTable` and `recordsSerialized`

```
$('#displayRecords').dataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
    "url": "globalJSON/recordsTable.php",
    "dataSrc": function (json) {
      // do something with json.recordsSerialized here
      return json.recordsTable;
    }
  }
});
```

I'm sure you've been looking at this already but here's the link to the documentation anyway: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: Bingo. Exactly what I needed, many thanks. And yes, been reading the documentation.